# Gson: deserialize lists of linked objects

Tags: java, json, jackson, kotlin, gson

I have two classes describing all of my data and one enum describing types of data

```
class Category(val name: String,
               val id: String,
               val type: CategoryType,
               val items: List<Item>)

class Item(val name: String,
           val id: String,
           val type: CategoryType,
           val data: Any?,
           val categoryIds: Array<String>)

enum class CategoryType {
    TYPE_A,
    TYPE_B,
    TYPE_C
}
```

and following JSON input

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": "category_id_1",
      "name": "Category 1",
      "type1": "TYPE_A",
      "type2": "TYPE_C"
    },
    {
      "id": "category_id_2",
      "name": "Category 2",
      "type1": "TYPE_B"
    },
    {
      "id": "category_id_3",
      "name": "Category 3",
      "type1": "TYPE_A"
    },
    {
      "id": "category_id_4",
      "name": "Category 4",
      "type1": "TYPE_C"
    }
  ],
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "item_id_1",
      "name": "Item 1",
      "type2": "TYPE_A",
      "categoryIds": [
        "category_id_4",
        "category_id_3"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "item_id_2",
      "name": "Item 2",
      "type1": "TYPE_C",
      "categoryIds": [
        "category_id_1"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

There are two major requirements:

1. I need to create two instances of `Category` with same `id` if there
   are both `type1` and `type2` listed in there.
2. I need to place same instance of `Item` in each `Category` instance if item has same `type1` and/or `type2` and `Category`'s `id` is listed in `Item`'s `categoryIds`.

For each `CategoryType` I can use any type of container like that`val typedAsTYPE_A: List<Category>`.

So the question is: how can I do that without using huge `com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer` constructions? Can it be done using `Gson` or am I supposed to use something like `Jackson`?

Comment: Why are the two points you noted "problems"? They sound like requirements to me. Did you try implementing anything yet? I would start using Jackson.

Comment: @PaulGeorgPodlech, thanks for suggestion, I improved my question. Yes, I implemented a couple of custom `JsonDeserializer`s, but they are really ugly and unmaintainable. I need more robust and flexible way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer: I am not familiar with Gson, but since you wanted to use it I tried to put something together. Most likely there are better ways to achieve the same results. The code is probably not robust and may contain mistakes.**

I hope my code is understandable enough. Basically it's those steps:

1. use Gson to parse to com.google.gson.JsonObject
2. use JsonObject to iterate over every item and add it to the appropriate list (or create the list if not existing)
3. iterate over every category and use the already generated list to add the items

Here's the code:

```
// Helper extension property for easily mapping Strings
// to their enum CategoryType
val String.catType: CategoryType?
    get() = CategoryType.values().find { it.toString() == this }

fun deserialize(json: String): Map<CategoryType, List<Category>> {
    // initialize the return value
    val categories = CategoryType.values().map { it to (mutableListOf<Category>()) }.toMap()
    // parse json
    val input = Gson().fromJson(json, com.google.gson.JsonObject::class.java)


    // accumulate itemLists for constructing Categories later
    // those lists will be looked up via CategoryType and CategoryId
    val itemLists = CategoryType.values().map { it to (mutableMapOf<String, MutableList<Item>>()) }.toMap()
    input["items"].asJsonArray.map { it.asJsonObject }.forEach { item ->
        // read properties for item
        val types = item.entrySet().filter { it.key.startsWith("type") }.map { it.value.asString.catType }
        val ids = item.getAsJsonArray("categoryIds").map { it.asString }
        val name = item["name"].asString
        val item_id = item["id"].asString
        val data = item["data"]
        //
        types.forEach { type ->
            type?.let {
                val itemObj = Item(name, item_id, type, data, ids.toTypedArray())
                ids.forEach { id ->
                    with(itemLists[type]!!) {
                        if (!this?.containsKey(id)) this[id] = mutableListOf(itemObj)
                        else this[id]?.add(itemObj)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // go through all categories and create appropriate objects
    input["categories"].asJsonArray.map { it.asJsonObject }.forEach { cat ->
        val id = cat["id"].asString
        val name = cat["name"].asString
        val types = cat.entrySet().filter { it.key.startsWith("type") }.map { it.value.asString.catType }
        types.forEach { type ->
            type?.let {
                categories[type]
                        ?.add(Category(
                                name = name,
                                id = id,
                                type = type,
                                items = itemLists[type]?.get(id) ?: listOf()))
            }
        }
    }

    return categories
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for the Json you provided.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = YOURJSON
ContainerObject myObj = gson.fromJson(json, ContainerObject.class);
//above code is placed where you want to deserialize the object

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ContainerObject {
    private ArrayList<Categories> categories;
    private ArrayList<Item> items;

    public ContainerObject(){

    }

    public ArrayList<Categories> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    public void setCategories(ArrayList<Categories> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }

    public ArrayList<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(ArrayList<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

}

import java.util.List;

public class Categories {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private CategoryType type1;
    private CategoryType type2;

    public Categories(){

    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public CategoryType getType1() {
        return type1;
    }

    public void setType1(CategoryType type1) {
        this.type1 = type1;
    }

    public CategoryType getType2() {
        return type2;
    }

    public void setType2(CategoryType type2) {
        this.type2 = type2;
    }

}


import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Item {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private CategoryType type1;
    private CategoryType type2;
    private ArrayList<String> categoryIds;

    public Item(){

    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public CategoryType getType1() {
        return type1;
    }

    public void setType1(CategoryType type1) {
        this.type1 = type1;
    }

    public CategoryType getType2() {
        return type2;
    }

    public void setType2(CategoryType type2) {
        this.type2 = type2;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getCategoryIds() {
        return categoryIds;
    }

    public void setCategoryIds(ArrayList<String> categoryIds) {
        this.categoryIds = categoryIds;
    }
}


public enum CategoryType {
    TYPE_A,
    TYPE_B,
    TYPE_C
}
```

Comment: It is a really nice solution, but I don't need both `type1` and `type2` to be listed in `Item` or `Category` classes (take a look at classes provided in question). The goal is to deserialize _one item_ with both types `{..."type1": "?", "type2": "?"...}` as _two different items_ with only _one type_

Comment: What you're saying is not really making much sense. Regardless I'm getting the impression that you will need to implement a custom deserializer and there won't be a way to make it "not ugly".